# PrintWriter and OutputStream for a simple client server socket program

Tags: java, sockets

I was following this tutorial (dateserver) on Socket programming in Java:

http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/javanetexamples/

This is the piece of code i don't understand:

```
try {
       PrintWriter out =
       new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
       out.println(new Date().toString());
                }
```

What is PrintWriter doing here? why we need to set the parameter to 'true?' i guess first we enable outputstream for the socket (by making it `true`) and then with the `out.println` we send date as outputstream, is my assumption right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Javadocs, the `PrintWriter` class "prints formatted representations of objects to a text-output stream". In this case it is printing the date to the output stream attached to the socket.

`true` in the constructor means subsequent call to `out.println(new Date().toString())` will automatically flush the buffer of the output stream, meaning it will force the string to be written to the stream, instead of storing the string in a temporary buffer.

Answer (score 2):

> What is `PrintWriter` doing here? why we need to set the parameter to 'true?' i guess first we enable outputstream for the socket (by making it true) and then with the out.println we send date as outputstream, is my assumption right?

Your assumption is wrong. Read more about it below.

```
new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
```

What JavaDoc of [PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter%28java.io.OutputStream,%20boolean%29) states:

> Creates a new `PrintWriter` from an existing `OutputStream`. This convenience constructor creates the necessary intermediate `OutputStreamWriter`, which will convert characters into bytes using the default character encoding.

1. Here `PrintWriter` stream is connected to the client/server's output stream it means any data written by print writer will sent to client/server.
2. Here `true` means *Auto-flush* the data from the output buffer once *new line* methods are called such as `println()`, `printf()`, or `format()` or any newline character ('\n') is found in the string. In that case you don't need to call `flush()` method manually.

Answer (score 0):

The PrintWriter object is created to write to the OutputStream object, true is used for flushing the stream, check the constructor in the API here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html